# SQL : select statement with aggregate function column without filter and another column with filter

Tags: sql

I have table with select query as shown below

```
SELECT
    AVG([ScoreAverage]) AS OverallAverage, 
    COUNT(*) AS ScoreCount 
FROM 
    [Score]
```

I have another column `StatusId` in the `[Score]` table.

In the above `SELECT` statement, I want to calculate another aggregate column `COUNT(*) WHERE StatusId = 4`.

Is it possible to do it in same select statement, or I do I need to query that separately?

```
SELECT
    AVG([ScoreAverage]) AS OverallAverage, 
    COUNT(*) AS ScoreCount, 
    COUNT(?Status where it is '4'?) AS CountOfStatusFour 
FROM
    [Score]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with `case when` expression as below:

```
select AVG([ScoreAverage]) AS OverallAverage, COUNT(*) AS ScoreCount, sum(case when Statusid ='4' then 1 else 0 end) AS CountOfStatusFour 
from [Score]
```

`CountOfStatusFour` will only count rows if for which `Statusid` is '4'

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.